# Cannot deploy Fiori application from VS Code to SAP S4/HANA Public Cloud

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform, s4hana, abap-adt

I am a newbie to SAP S4/HANA Cloud. This is my first time to demo a new Fiori application and deploy it to the public cloud. I used Visual Studio as a development tool. However, when I run the command "npm run deploy" from Visual Studio Code to deploy the project, I receive the following error message: "Command deploy failed with error Request failed with status code 403." When I tried to configure the development environment, I received the following error message: "Cannot get transport configuration from the backend Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80."

I am unsure whether I have missed assigning a role to the user for deploying an application to the ABAP environment. Is it correct to Create a Communication user for credentials because now I use Communication user and tried to find Which Scenario to add for create communication arrangement cause now SAP Web IDE Integration (Obsolete).

My system doesn't have BTP and I understand that we can't use sap GUI for work around as below.
**Prerequisites for deploy to ABAP system**

1. Activate the /UI5/ABAP_REPOSITORY_SRV service in your back-end system
2. You have S_DEVELOP authorization in your backend system for your user

Is it possible to do this on public cloud. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial as a work around using BAS;
https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/abap-custom-ui-bas-develop-s4hc.html

To deploy to your target ABAP system, you need a business user configured with the appropriate privileges. Deploying using a communication user is not sufficient. A COM user is really only use for generating and consuming OData XML services.